# Testing status code expects 500 instead of 200

Tags: phpunit, symfony4

I'm writing my firsts tests with Symfony 4.1, and I'm experiencing an odd problem. The test is to make sure the endpoint returns status 200:

```
public function testFetchTaskEndpointStatusCode200()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request("GET", "/tasks");

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

The endpoint then triggers the following method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/tasks")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function fetchAction()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Task::class);
    $tasks = $repository->findAll();

    return $this->json([
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
}
```

Using Insomnia software and through browser, I can see the returned status is 200, but when executing the test:

> Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

At testing time some error occurs on your server side code, hence the error code 500. Since we cannot see your testcase and setup it will be hard for us to guide you

Comment: But why does it work when accessing via browser and REST software? Also, the test is there. Where do I find the setup?

Comment: Not sure, perhaps there is a session when you test it in your browser and not so when you run the test case? Are you using some authentication system?

Comment: I used `var_dump` on the `getContent()`, and I can see messages saying the access to the database has been denied. Shouldn't `.env` work as well for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
<phpunit>
    ...
    <!-- define your env variables for the test env here -->
    <env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/database" />
</phpunit>
```

to `phpunit.xml.dist` solved it.